# Use constant property to build another property inside the same constant angularjs

Tags: angularjs, properties, constants

In short my problem is this: I want to use angular constant functionality to save values that I will need in my app. I was wandering if one could build a property using the value of another property of the same constant. Like this:

```
app.constant("url", {
   basicUrl: "/svc",
   managementPanel: basicUrl + "/managemnent.html"
   // and so on...
});
```

Is there any way one can achieve this? I tried using the "this" keyword but it referenced the window object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put it all to function:

```
(function() {
  var constant = {};

  constant.base = 'base';
  constant.nested = constant.base + '/nested';
  constant.nested2 = constant.nested + '/nested2';

  app.constant('test', constant)
})();
```

Comment: What if I want to use "nested" in another property inside the same constant?

Comment: I enjoyed this last solution! Please modify your initial answer so that I can choose your answer as the most satisfying (although one can derive from the initial answer the later one).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a factory instead of the constant shorthand for this.

```
app.factory("url", function() {
  var url = {};
  url.basicUrl = "/svc";
  url.managementPanel = url.basicUrl +  "/managemnent.html";
  return url;
})
```